# python 3 'input()' with textmate 2 'run'?

Tags: python-3.x, textmate2

I have python 3.5.2 installed with homebrew (El Capitan). I have TextMate 2.

I have a .tm_properties file in my project folder which successfully gets textmate 2 to run python 3.5.2

(I would like to learn python, and would prefer to use textmate, instead of IDLE.)

What I don't know is how to get a command like

```
input()
```

to succeed.

```
(EOFError: 'EOF when reading a line')
```

addition: I have received a link to a possible duplicate of this question. Firstly in the other question (which I have seen) the problem was not solved - the answer was that it was not possible (at that time). Secondly, this was 6 years ago, and we are now on textmate 2, so I am hoping somebody has found a solution?
ALSO: Choosing the python version can now be done on a project basis with adding a .tm_properties file to the project: Choosing the version of python is not my problem. If the other post is correct, the problem lies in textmate not redirecting standard input. This problem (if that is the problem) is not resolved.

Comment: This is the result I would expect if you run this command with Python 2 and press Enter instead of entering input. It should not do that with Python 3. Are you sure Textmate is using Python 3 to interpret your script? You could add `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` to the top of your script to test this. Alternatively, you can use `import platform; print(platform.python_version())`

Comment: yes, textmate is running python 3.5.2 (sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0))

Comment: This is not a duplicate, see my addition in the main body of the question. Thank you!